# Best way to dynamically load Assets in Unity WebGL Builds from external Source during Runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

Ive got a Unity WebGL Build with alot of Assets (1k+) that keep increasing. Everytime a new Asset gets added the whole Thing has to be built again which takes a lot of Time.
I only need a small Amount of the Assets during Runtime but i cant know which Assets exactly (The User can decide which Assets to actually use and see during Runtime).
Ive heard about Asset Bundles but i dont quite understand them yet. Is it possible to have some Sort of external Server running on its own with all the Assets there and then have the WebGL Build load the specific Assets it needs during Runtime from that Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Addressable Asset System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.16/manual/index.html) with remote catalog for dynamic asset delivery using any CDN. Every time you run your game Addressable Asset System will download assets dynamically & asynchronously. This feature is successor of old asset bundle system.

Comment: That looks perfect, thank you very much.